# Создание кнопок на основе списка

Tags: python, frontend

Допустим, есть у меня некий список из Python. Вопрос такой: как из него можно было бы сделать что-то типа кнопок на фронтэнде (каждая кнопка соответствует элементу списка). Пользователь нажимает на кнопки, и создает новый список...

Я в frontend вообще не силен, поэтому буду рад любой информации
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А java при чём в данном вопросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужен сервер который отправит список на "фронт". Предварительно на сервере список превращаем в JSon строку. На "фронте" получаем и с помощью javascript делаем кнопки. И все остальное что нужно...